# Javascript event listener not working for opening a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having issues with getting event listeners to work, I had it working so multiple different buttons opened one modal, then when trying to make it so the different buttons would load different modals the code has broken and I can't get make any button load any modal now. If anyone has any fixes to this, I'm sure it's a stupid issue due to me being a complete beginner, it would be much appreciated. I've tried to undo my code to where I was but the issue didn't resolve itself.

```js
document.getElementByID('TrainBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'flex';
}) 

document.getElementByID('Project2Btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'flex';
}) 


document.querySelector('.close-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
body {
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px; 
    text-align: center;

}

.horizontalLine {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto

}


.gallery {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center; /*makes individual boxes centered*/
}
.gallery img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px; 
}

.gallery .projectBox {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin: 10px; /*can be used to make the photos spaced out*/*/
}


.gallery .projectBox img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;

}

/*when hover over image, the image disappears*/
.gallery .projectBox:hover img {
    opacity: 0; 
    
}

.gallery .projectBox .span {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;

}

.gallery .projectBox .span p1 {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.gallery .projectBox .span p2 {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.gallery .projectBox:hover .span {
    opacity: 1; 
    display: block;

}


.gallery .projectBox .span a {
    
    text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery .projectBox .span .btn {

    display: flex; /*makes layout nice :) */
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px; /*how far the lines of button are from text*/
    margin: 30px auto; 
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.gallery .projectBox .span .btn:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #f44336;
       
}




/* popups */
.bg-modal {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex; /*makes it a flex box*/
    justify-content: center; /*all items in box center vertically*/
    align-items: center; /*all items in box center horizontally*/
    
    display: none;
}


.modal-content {
    opacity: 1; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%; 
    background-color: white; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    position: relative; /*lets the .close position itself according to content*/
}

/*image for top of modal*/
.modal-content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.modal-content .close-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 14px;
    font-size: 42px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/935b67cf83.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script defer src="JS.js"></script> <!-- used to link to javascript-->


    <title>yo</title>
</head>


<body>



    <section class="flex" id="portfolio">

        <h1>
            PROJECTS
            <div class="horizontalLine" </div>
        </h1>

        

        <div class="gallery">

            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <a class="btn" id="TrainBtn" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <a class="btn" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <a class="btn" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>


                </div>

            </div>

           

        </div>
            

        
    </section>


    <!--pop-ups, bg-modal means background-->
    <div class="bg-modal" id="trainModal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />

                    <div class="close-button">
                        &times;
                    </div>

                    <h2> MerseyTrainsLive</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p> idem espum </p>

                </div>

            </div>

    </div>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: The browser's development console is alerting you to the typo in your code.  `getElementByID` is not a function.  But `getElementById` is.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change getElementByID to getElementById. 'd' is letter case.

Second, there's no element that has id name 'Project2Btn'. So, you should change your id of element at least 1 or change the id to find right one.

You can check the console and how logs are written.

```js
document.getElementById('TrainBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'flex';
  console.log('getElementById');
}) 


document.querySelector('.close-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'none';
      console.log('querySelector')
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/935b67cf83.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script defer src="JS.js"></script> <!-- used to link to javascript-->


    <title>yo</title>
</head>


<body>




    <section class="flex" id="portfolio">

        <h1>
            PROJECTS
            <div class="horizontalLine" </div>
        </h1>

        

        <div class="gallery">

            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <a id="TrainBtn" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <a class="btn" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <a class="btn" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>


                </div>

            </div>

           

        </div>
            

        
    </section>


    <!--pop-ups, bg-modal means background-->
    <div class="bg-modal" id="trainModal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />

                    <div class="close-button">
                        &times;
                    </div>

                    <h2> MerseyTrainsLive</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p> idem espum </p>

                </div>

            </div>

    </div>




</body>


</html>
```